# Possible ActiveRecord issue when trying to install Foundation 5.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, zurb-foundation-5

```
OS: Windows 10
Ruby: 2.1.5
Rails: 4.1.8
```

I am trying to use foundation-rails 5.5.

```
bundle install and bundle update
```

Do not produce any errors.

When I do:

```
generate simple_form:install --foundation
```

I get a very long listing of warnings/errors, that start with the following:

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/orm_adapter-0.5.0/lib/orm_adapter/adapters/active_record.rb:81: warning: already initialized constant ActiveRecord::Base::OrmAdapter
```

When I do:

```
gem list
```

I get the following:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.1.8)
actionpack (4.1.8)
actionview (4.1.8)
activemodel (4.1.8)
activerecord (4.1.8)
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.1.0)
activesupport (4.1.8)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
bcrypt (3.1.10 x86-mingw32)
better_errors (2.1.1)
bigdecimal (1.2.4)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.7.7)
coderay (1.1.0)
coffee-rails (4.1.0)
coffee-script (2.4.1, 2.3.0)
coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1, 1.8.0)
devise (3.5.2)
devise_invitable (1.5.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.6.0, 2.2.2)
foundation-rails (5.5.3.1)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.7.0, 0.7.0.beta1)
io-console (0.4.2)
jbuilder (2.3.2)
jquery-rails (3.1.4, 3.1.2)
json (1.8.3, 1.8.1)
mail (2.6.3)
mime-types (2.6.2, 2.4.3)
minitest (5.8.1, 5.4.3, 4.7.5)
multi_json (1.11.2, 1.10.1)
mysql2 (0.4.1 ruby x86-mingw32)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
pg (0.17.1 x86-mingw32)
psych (2.0.5)
quiet_assets (1.1.0)
rack (1.5.5, 1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.3, 0.6.2)
rails (4.1.8)
rails_apps_pages (0.6.0)
rails_layout (1.0.26)
railties (4.1.8)
rake (10.4.2, 10.1.0)
rb-readline (0.5.1)
rdoc (4.1.0)
responders (1.1.2)
rubyzip (1.1.6)
sass (3.4.18, 3.2.19)
sass-rails (5.0.4, 4.0.5)
simple_form (3.2.0)
sprockets (3.4.0, 3.0.0.beta.4, 2.12.3)
sprockets-rails (2.3.3, 2.2.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.10 x86-mingw32)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
test-unit (2.1.5.0)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5, 0.3.4)
tilt (2.0.1, 1.4.1)
turbolinks (2.5.3)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
tzinfo-data (1.2015.7)
uglifier (2.7.2)
warden (1.2.3)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `orm_adapter` is loaded twice. The message says you are **not** using Ruby `2.1.5` (as you wrote) but Ruby `2.1.0`, so there may be conflicting versions installed.

You should use [rvm](http://blog.developwithpassion.com/2012/03/30/installing-rvm-with-cygwin-on-windows/) to manage Ruby versions and gems to avoid conflicts and specify the Ruby version for which the app is written in your Gemfile.

Comment: rvm does not run on Windows. Please see my question. This is also 2.1.5, the Railsinstaller for Windows puts the binaries/libs/gems in a 2.1.0 directories

Comment: If you don't use rvm running `rake rails:update` may help with this issue. 
I have seen people using rvm on windows with cygwin. 
Can you add the Gemfile to the question?

Comment: cygwin is not Windows. It would be like running a VM under Windows and running linux or something else on it. rake rails:update does not work. All it does is make unnecessary changes to some of the initialization files.

Comment: I can run  `rails generate simple_form:install --foundation` in windows with ruby 2.1.5, rails 4.1.8 and all gems in your list installed. No error here. Can you provide more infos how to reproduce this?

Comment: Which DB gem are you using?